# Appending a new node to linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

Basically what title says, Im trying to append (add to end of my list). my BuildList function takes in a size parameter that determines how many nodes the list will have. my problem is with my append function. So if I have 5 as my head, how do I fix my append function so that random numbers will be added after 5?

```
typedef struct Node
{
    int value;
    struct Node* next;
} Node;

Node *createNode( int num )
{
    Node *ptr;
    ptr = (Node *) malloc( sizeof( Node ) );

    ptr->value = num;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    return ptr;
}
Node* append (Node* head, Node* newNode)
{


    if (head == NULL)
        return newNode;

    while (head -> next != NULL);

    head -> next = newNode;
    return head;
}
Node* buildList (int size)
{
    Node* newNode = (Node*) malloc (sizeof(Node));
    Node* head = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Node* newNode = createNode (rand () % 10);
        head = append (head, newNode);
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `while` loop in `append`?

Comment: In `append`, you're overwriting `head->next`.  What if `head->next` wasn't `NULL`?  You just lost access to all of the following nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the most glaring issue is this

```
while (head -> next != NULL);
```

I believe you meant to write something like this

```
Node *tmp = head;
while (tmp -> next != NULL) {
    tmp = tmp->next;
}
tmp->next = newNode;
```

You don't want to modify `head` here since you return it later in the function. If you didn't use `tmp`, head would always point to the penultimate node in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify your while, why do you have an empty instruction there? If the head is not NULL then you will never exit:

```
while (head -> next != NULL)
{
    head = head -> next;
}
```